# Lualatex: Check if graphic exists otherwise use file

Tags: graphics, luatex

The usage `\includegraphics[width=1.7cm]{MyImage}` is quite simple straight forward. If file `MyImage` doesn't exist the whole process is cancelled. Therefore I want to check in advance if the file exists - otherwise print some generic warnings - the best would be using it in an own command, e.g.

```
\newcommand{\useGraphic}[2]{
  \IfFileExists{#1}{
    \includegraphics[#2]{#1}
  }{
    \input{#1}    % The warnings will be in the tex file (e.g. MyImage.tex)
  }
}
```

The major problem I have with this kind of approach is that the file could be either `MyImage.png` or `MyImage.jpeg` or ... Since I don't want to specify them individually is there an easier way to handle it? Is it better to handle it with LaTeX code or via LuaTeX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `gincltex`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{gincltex}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\usegraphics}[2][]{%
  \begingroup
  \edef\Gin@extensions{\Gin@extensions,.tex}
  \includegraphics[#1]{#2}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\usegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}

\usegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a.png}

\usegraphics[width=3cm]{qwertyuiop}

\end{document}
```

By default, `.tex` is not added to the list of extensions, so I do it locally.

The file `qwertyuiop.tex` contains `\fbox{WARNING}`.

[image]

Comment: This won't handle images found through \graphicspath.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer exercise for the reader

Comment: ;-). It wasn't asked for in the question but I thought it should be mentioned.

Comment: Well - that's close to the solution I'm looking for. The major problem I have with this version is - the same with my inital own approach - how to check if `MyImage` doesn't exist as `MyImage.tex`. Because I don't need the `tex` file - since this will have my Error messsages. And with `MyImage.tex` the compilation fails. Hmmm... seems like I missed this tiny(?) part at the beginning. :-/

Comment: @LeO Please, add the details, I’ll add support for `\graphicspath`

Comment: @egreg I don't think I need the `\graphicspath` at all. Because the files are automatically in the proper folder. Therefore I don't need that feature (and didn't mention it). I just want to check if a given file-name is there - if yes ==> use `\includegraphics` otherwise use `input` (I've updated the original q as well)

Comment: @egreg I have posted a feature request on  latex2e repository and I think this is exactly what I want,  can you take a look 
https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/178

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It was simpler, actually.

Comment: Wonderful  - this approach works very well although I need a new package.

Answer (score 1):

The package is already testing for the file and making an error so you can just downgrade that to a warning. You could add more code depending what you want to do instead of display the file but....

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\zzz[2][]{{%
\def\@latex@error##1##2{\@warning{##1}}%
\def\PackageError##1##2##3{\PackageWarning{##1}{##2}}%
\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\zzz{missingfile}



\zzz[width=.5\textwidth]{missingfile}


\zzz{missingfile.png}

\end{document}
```

Comment: So basically I should add after `\PackageWarning` code like `\input`? Do I understand this correctly? Although I'm quite sure that it will work (in my case) doesn't this introduce additional problems in case the inserted command fails?

Comment: @LeO well it depends what you insert, if you just insert `\textbf{missing file here}` then it basically can't fail, otherwise if you get braver the worst that happens is that an error is reported as a warning

Comment: Well although the approach with `\textbf` works I cannot use this with `\input`. Or at least I didn't figure it out how and where to place it properly. Could it be that `\input` is a LaTeX command while the redefinition is on TeX level? If so, is there an equivalent?

Comment: @LeO It is not clear why you need input, you could instead of just redefining PackageError and latex@error copy the code from graphics.sty and pdftex.def 9look for `not found` errors and insert your `\input` at those places, but do you really want a custom tex file for every missing image  do you need to recursively check if that file exits?